# Backbone Post JSON Null?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a basic backbone on rails survey app to understand nested models and interacting with the server. I'm struggling with actually creating the choices after the user selects them.

This is a curl request that works/ideally what it should be from a JSON/POST perspective:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/choices -d '{"answer_id":"3", "appuser_id":"1", "question_id":"2"}'
```

Here's how I'm creating it:

```
updateQuestion: ->
    if @questionNumber < @questionLimit
      @questionNumber += 1
      $("#container").html(@render().el)
      choice = new SurveyMe.Models.Choice
      choice.appuser = Cookie.get('user')
      choice.question = 3
      choice.answer = 4
      choice.save()
    else
      Backbone.history.navigate("surveys",trigger: true)
```

And the Choice model:

```
class SurveyMe.Models.Choice extends Backbone.RelationalModel

    urlRoot: '/choices'
```

I *think* that the JSON might be coming out as null? Any idea why that might be or what I need to do to create the JSON above in the curl?

Headers:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/choices
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:request_method=GET; user=6c7f11ad2bd9d825cc89f77b8f24d008; _survey_me_session=ZTh0MHVsUTd0amx6YnpPMEs3NlE4OWtkM0dDdjEzNndzUFc0OFdMS1NSWFZibHJFRXpDdGJRdVZETW9qSUQ3dUNVZjF1Q2QrdndKWVBWN1Z0M2VwRnZRSU95a3ZrU1JPSjArMjgxdmFMT3FXSk43L21kOTQxdVJJejZjb1p5V21EdUIwenlKbjc1dFlCbUtXd3B6TTNKRjhqSGxvd0FobC9Nblo4Y0xRL0VXMjhqb2xrb3B1Ryt3UnRERUFDRGhnLS1NWGc4eGlKSzRTZm96azJqL0ZhbjhRPT0%3D--f00afae157b22e2f4f5a052e415603070b476f2e
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/surveys/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token:yJTVE9Ce+a6uIfHk7QmXZsRtg4i7kAoFKjGzXs1Ileg=
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source
{}
No Properties
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:16491
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 29 Jun 2014 03:22:21 GMT
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-05-14)
X-Request-Id:4276e2be-224c-4829-87ce-0a40e960d5dd
X-Runtime:0.105006
```

Preview:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ChoicesController#create
param not found: choice

Extracted source (around line #48):
4647484950          
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def choice_params
      params.require(:choice).permit(:appuser_id, :answer_id, :question_id)
    end
end
Rails.root: C:/Users/thammond/Documents/GitHub/Survey.me

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/choices_controller.rb:48:in `choice_params'app/controllers/choices_controller.rb:12:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"choice"=>{}}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone model attributes and JavaScript object properties on the model are entirely different things. When you say this:

```
choice.appuser = Cookie.get('user')
```

you're setting the `appuser` *property*, not the `appuser` *attribute*. Backbone models only know about *attributes* when you do CRUD operations on them. You want to use [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) to set the attributes so that `save` will know about them:

```
choice = new SurveyMe.Models.Choice
choice.set('appuser', Cookie.get('user'))
choice.set('question', 3)
choice.set('answer, 4)
choice.save()
```

or set them all at once:

```
choice = new SurveyMe.Models.Choice
choice.set(
  appuser: Cookie.get('user')
  question: 3
  answer: 4
)
choice.save()
```

or even hand them to [`save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

```
choice = new SurveyMe.Models.Choice
choice.save(
  appuser: Cookie.get('user')
  question: 3
  answer: 4
)
```